# What is the role of boost in range query in elastic-search

Tags: elasticsearch

what is the relevant of boost in a range query
How to find the execution time its takes while running

```
GET bank/account/_search
{
  "query":{
    "range":{
      "account_number":{
        "gte": 516,
        "lte": 851,
        "boost": 2
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Elasticsearch Range Query Document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html)

> `boost (Optional, float)`
> Floating point number used to decrease or increase the relevance scores of a query. Defaults to 1.0.
> You can use the boost parameter to adjust relevance scores for searches containing two or more queries.
> Boost values are relative to the default value of 1.0. A boost value between 0 and 1.0 decreases the relevance score. A value greater than 1.0 increases the relevance score.

The boost value here will increase the relevance score of the document if the query match the document. Your search query is not benefit from the boost as it contains only a single query condition.

If you use `boost` with multiple queries condition ([boolean query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) for example), then the document that match the query with `boost` will have a higher/lower `_score` in the result.